# Gradle DSL method not found: 'main()'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

syncing Gradle it gives the following error
Error:(24, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'main()'
Possible causes:

The project 'OcrAgainNew' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

"gradle.build"

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
   }
}

sourceSets.main {
    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    java.srcDirs = ['src']
    resources.srcDirs = ['src']
    res.srcDirs = ['res']
    jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
}
```

[screenshot of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1njAQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the `sourceSets` block inside the `android` block

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
   defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 23
   }

   sourceSets.main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
      java.srcDirs = ['src']
      resources.srcDirs = ['src']
      res.srcDirs = ['res']
      jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version `0.14.0` or higher of the gradle plugin, you should replace `runProguard` with `minifyEnabled` in your `build.gradle` files.

Comment: it is minifyEnabled instead of runProguard. the error it gives is, it says "main method not found"